# downloading a file from server in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to download a file from my server.

Here is my code for controller.

```
public function download($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $base_url = $this->config->item('base_url');
    $base_path = $this->config->item('base_path');
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $data = file_get_contents( $base_path.'/uploads/'.$id);
    $name = $id;
    force_download($name, $data);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
file_get_contents(path/filename): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

How can I solve this problem?Thank's

the problem is in the path itself. actually its not taking filenames with space between them. for ex. it's working fine now with filename xyz but not with filename ex. try xyz. I think it's because of the space in between the name. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Check for the path of your file if it correct or file is present there. Try to echo the path firstly

Comment: check the value of

echo $base_path.'/uploads/'.$id;die;

Comment: yeah  the problem was in the path itself. actually its not taking filenames with spcae between them. for ex. it's working fine now with filename xyz but not with filename ex. try xyz. I think it's because of the space in bebtween the name. how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use curl instead.
This might be your answer.

http://www.technologyworkshops.net/php/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-to-local-path-using-curl-t132.html

add the function in your helper and it works well.

AS LINK IS BROKEN PASTIN CODE HERE

Sharing with you to a piece of code that will save a file to your local directory using curl.

```
$getFile = 'https://url to file/file_name.csv';
$getParams  = array ();

$path = '/var/save/to/local/path/file_name&#46;csv';
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($getFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(fwrite($fp,$data))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. You should only post links for reference information and always provide an example in code.

Comment: @tomasantunes done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path to the magic constant __ DIR__

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

```
$data = file_get_contents( __ DIR__.'/../uploads/'.$id);
```